# How to take the exact value next to a date cell to another sheet or table in Excel?

Tags: excel, function, date, excel-formula, vlookup

I need to take the value corresponding to a certain date, and use it in another table or sheet:

In one sheet, I have two columns, one for the dates (every day of the year) and the other for the fixed values.

In the other sheet, I need to take those fixed values according to the date, which I enter manually.

Tried using the IF function with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using [=VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx):

[image: SO18213770 example]

Comment: Worked perfectly, it's better to use semicolons, at least in Excel 2003.

Also I used it with Libreoffice Calc, with minimal variation. It's necessary to include the full range of cells. Following your example:
"=VLOOKUP(A5;Sheet1.A2:B10;2;0)"

Thanks very much.